# getting error @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function | composable inside pointerInput

Tags: android, events, drag, modifier, composable

I want to call Text inside detectDragGestures it gives error

> error: @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

```
Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragStart = { touch ->
                    Text("0")
                },
                
            )
        }
    )
```

Comment: You can't - `onDragStart` lambda/closure is not a composable function.  However you can use that lambda to mutate a state object, that updates something in that content thats reads the state if you wish.

Comment: Do you want to show dragValue to ```Text``` or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `Text` composable on drag then you manage a `mutableState` like in this sample.

```
val showText = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

if(showText)
    Text("0")

Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragStart = { touch ->
                    showText.value = true
                },
                //...
            )
    }
)
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set the variable to `false` after drag ends.

Also you can animate the `Text` using `AnimatedVisibility`.